# Induced mappings

Tags: functions, relations

Suppose $f$ is a mapping from the powerset of $A$ to the powerset of $B$. Let $S$ and $T$ be subsets of $A$. If both $f(\varnothing)=\varnothing$, and $f(S \cup T) = f(S) \cup f(T)$, then is $f$ the induced mapping of a unique relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$?

If not, what if I strengthen the second condition to hold for arbitary unions, not just finite ones?

Comment: This may sound harsh, but your post consists of a somewhat interesting question and a trivial one, and if you do not have an answer for the trivial one then that makes me suspect that an answer to the more interesting one would be wasted on you. Nevertheless, HINT: For each set $S$ you have $S=\bigcup_{x\in S}\{x\}$.

Comment: Okay, I know the answer to my second question now. Now, what is the answer to the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set $A$ is finite, then its powerset, $P(A)$ is finite, too, and 2. implies that $f$ preserves all finite unions.

If $f$ preserves *all unions*, i.e. $f\left(\bigcup_i X_i\right)=\bigcup_i\,f(X_i)$ for any collection of sets $X_i\subseteq A$, then let $aRb$ iff $b\in f(\{a\})$ defines the unique relation $f$ is induced by.

If $A$ is infinite, and $f$ preserves only finite unions, then it should not be true in general. Looking for a counterexample, $A$ must be infinite and we can spoil up a mapping induced by relation by redefining it for the infinite case.
So let $A:=\Bbb N$. Let $f:P(\Bbb N)\to P(\Bbb N)$ be the identity on finite sets, but let it map all infinite sets to the whole $\Bbb N$.